# Storing two values in an array python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

Hi im sure there is a much more efficient way of coding this, im primarily a java programmer but trying to help some one out with some basic python.

I need to have a 2D array which contains a set of random co-ordinates eg (2, 10).
My initial thought was to create the array then fill it will smaller arrays containing the two co-ordinates.

```
import numpy
import random

a = numpy.zeros(10000).reshape(100, 100)
temp = []
for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        temp.append(random.randint(0,100))
        temp.append(random.randint(0,100))
        a[i][j]=temp

print a
```

This produces the error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

So whats the best way to go about solving this problem? Sorry for this hacked together code i've never really had to use python before!

Answer (score 2):

That is a three dim array, you can create it by:

```
np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100, 2))
```

Comment: will that create a 100 * 100 array with the co ordinates ?

Comment: @user2219545 That's a 100 * 100 * 2 array, where the two coordinates use the last dimension.

Comment: @user2219545 Janne means to say Yes!.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
import random
a = numpy.zeros((100, 100, 2))
for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        a[i,j,:] = (random.randint(0,100),
                    random.randint(0,100))
print 'x-coords:\n', a[:,:,0]
print 'y-coords:\n', a[:,:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

@HYRY gives the correct answer if I understand what you are trying to do.. The reason you get a Value error is because you are assigning a sequence, or python list (tmp) to a single float ( a[i][j] ). @HalCanary shows you how to do fix your code to get around this error, but HYRY's code should be optimal for python computing.